# How to squash a range of commits from the history of git?

Tags: git

I want to squash multiple commits together but none of them are the current head.
This is what it looks like:

```
commit 7e3641f857b4fb15362c43354de5f14846a461b1 (HEAD -> superset-custom-exporter, origin/superset-custom-exporter)
Author: Aviral Srivastava
Date:   Wed Nov 4 11:41:32 2020 -0500

    adds env vars pertaining to postgresdb deployment with odh

commit bae9321ea4f78973adcc50c92a10eaebd703c7eb
Author: 
Date:   Wed Oct 21 08:55:37 2020 -0300

    Fix the security role for new logged in users

commit 2974314ca485c526ed2272f6c8bad443653765ab
Author: 
Date:   Thu Oct 15 13:39:08 2020 -0400

    Revert "wip"
    
    This reverts commit 0a93c50120b49a6ad850ee0cf8b1ab0523d50f97.

commit second_commit
Author: 
Date:   Thu Oct 15 11:50:24 2020 -0400

    wip

commit some_commit
Author: 
Date:   Thu Oct 15 10:30:47 2020 -0400

    Upgrade to superset version 0.37.2

commit some_commit
Author: 
Date:   Thu Oct 22 12:40:49 2020 -0400

    wip

commit some_commit
Author: 
Date:   Thu Oct 22 12:19:47 2020 -0400

    adds slices monitoring

commit first_commit
Author: 
Date:   Thu Oct 15 16:07:03 2020 -0400
```

I want to squash the commits from hash `second_commit` to hash `first_commit` into one single commit. I understand how to do this from the current one with a range in the past but I do not know how to do this when both of the commits are in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You you use a command like `git rebase -i HEAD~8` and then change `pick` to `s` on the lines for each of the commits that you want to squash.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do an *interactive rebase*. This gives you a list of commits and lets you specify which ones you want to squash. Interactive rebase is a great way to clean up your commits while keeping the integrity of some of them.

Comment: Nice tutorial here: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history

Answer (score 0):

```
git rebase --interactive HEAD~[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--interactive` flag with `git rebase` to rewrite a series of commits up until a hash that you supply, e.g.:

```
git rebase --interactive 05a159
```

And obviously replacing **05a159** with your own sha. And as Jeff Scott Brown mentions, swap the `pick` with `squash` or `s` (using the short form).

When you re-write history in this way, you're creating a new object which consists of the squashed objects, and throwing away the old ones (until garbage colllected). If you regret this action, use `git reflog` to `git reset --hard` your branch to an older hash or simply create a local tag on the tip of your branch before starting the rebase.

Answer (score 0):

Actually to squash your project not only you should move head but also you should move master to the same position.

To do this
1.you should reset in soft >>>>>>> git reset --soft [second commit's hash value]
2.put your modified commit as the next commit >>git commit -am "The last commit"

now you have squashed.
Actually, use "git log --oneline " instead of "git log" command. It shorts your text.